# Mono for Android VS2010: Cannot view layout in designer

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, mono, xamarin.android, designer

I installed `Mono for Android` with the intention of using Visual Studio 2010 to design android apps. I am able to compile and deploy applications, but I am not able to view the layout designer. When I double click on an `.axml` file it opens in `source view` and there is no context menu option such as "View in designer." I am able to use `MonoDevelop` to create the layout, but I shouldn't have to do that.

Here are some screen caps:
[image]
[image]

Any tips?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with a refresh install today.

Comment: I believe the way I fixed it was by reinstalling.

Comment: @Mike you re-installed VS2010 or monodroid?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to simple but right clicking on the `Main.axml` in Visual Studio and select and choose *Open with*. Then select *Android Designer* should do the trick.

Despite that Android Designer can be set as Default it appears not to be working like that. I should say that's a BUG in VS and/or Monofor Android.

Answer (score 0):

Are you shure to have the latest Mono for Android installed? (Version 4.2.4)

The Open With Dialog should have an entry "Android Designer".

Select this now and click "Set as Default".

Comment: Yup had the latest version. "Android Designer" was missing from the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

Did a full uninstall, reinstall and reboot. 
At first it didn't seem to have fixed it - my existing hello world project still wouldn't open the designer.

I tried creating a new project and ta-da all good now! Very odd.

I've very pleased to have gui designer. It really helps level the learning curve when learning  a new platform - nice work Xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

I did 3 installs until it finally took. I uninstalled then reinstalled and it still didn't work. I then just did a repair and it finally worked. Just keep reinstalling and you'll get it.